# SBS 2003, shared calendars

Tags: exchange, share

We have a client who use shared calendars throughout the organisation but any time an invitation is sent to the owner of the calendar all users with access to the calendar receive the invitation too.

How can we limit so only the owner of the calendar receives the invitation?

We are using Exchange 2003 and outlook client is 2003/2007.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check Tools, Options, Delegates on the owner's outlook. Make sure the checkbox "Send meeting requests and responses only to my delegates, not to me" is unchecked.